Mermaid in Quarto can't use more than once
I am writing a large document (200+ pages) using quarto in R studio; after recent updates it will no longer render and I have traced to problem to the presence of two mermaid flow charts.
If I delete the mermaid chunks it renders perfectly ... if I add back 1 chunk it renders perfectly ... If I add back the second chunk it hangs; even adding back the working code chunk a second time causes it to hang !!
This code renders properly ...

    ---
    title: | 
        | XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        | XXXXXXXXXX
    subtitle: |
        | xxxxxxxxxxx
        |
        | 1st Edition
    date-format:  "YYYY"
    date: last-modified
    lang: en-GB
    format:
        pdf:
          indent: false
    fontsize: "10"
    ---
       
    # Preface
    
    Blah Blah Blah
    
    ## Flow chart
    
    ::: {#fig-BitDepth}
    ```{mermaid}
    %%| fig-width: 5
    flowchart LR
      A[analogue data] --> B(pre amplifier)
      B --> C{ADC}
      C --> D[14 bit ADC 16384 levels]
      C --> E[24 bit ADC 16777216 levels]

    Signal processing pathway and the effect of ADC bit depth on resolution.
    :::



But this code - using the exact code chunk twice - hangs ...
    ---
    title: | 
        | XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        | XXXXXXXXXX
    subtitle: |
        | xxxxxxxxxxx
        |
        | 1st Edition
    date-format:  "YYYY"
    date: last-modified
    lang: en-GB
    format:
        pdf:
          indent: false
    fontsize: "10"
    ---
       
    # Preface
    
    Blah Blah Blah
    
    ## Flow chart
    
    ::: {#fig-BitDepth}
    ```{mermaid}
    %%| fig-width: 5
    flowchart LR
      A[analogue data] --> B(pre amplifier)
      B --> C{ADC}
      C --> D[14 bit ADC 16384 levels]
      C --> E[24 bit ADC 16777216 levels]
  
    Signal processing pathway and the effect of ADC bit depth on resolution.
    :::
    
    ## Flow chart2
    
    ::: {#fig-BitDepth2}
    ```{mermaid}
    %%| fig-width: 5
    flowchart LR
      A[analogue data] --> B(pre amplifier)
      B --> C{ADC}
      C --> D[14 bit ADC 16384 levels]
      C --> E[24 bit ADC 16777216 levels]

    Signal processing pathway and the effect of ADC bit depth on resolution.
    :::


I have seen mysterious problems with mermaid before ... "unable to connect to localhost" type errors which were fixed with a quarto update but this doesn't seem to help this time.
Here are the details on the quarto version and dependencies ...
Quarto 1.5.57

    [✓] Checking versions of quarto binary dependencies...
          Pandoc version 3.2.0: OK
          Dart Sass version 1.70.0: OK
          Deno version 1.41.0: OK
          Typst version 0.11.0: OK
    [✓] Checking versions of quarto dependencies......OK
    [✓] Checking Quarto installation......OK
          Version: 1.5.57
          Path: /Applications/quarto/bin
    
    [✓] Checking tools....................OK
          TinyTeX: (not installed)
          Chromium: (not installed)
    
    [✓] Checking LaTeX....................OK
          Using: Installation From Path
          Path: /Library/TeX/texbin
          Version: 2024
    
    [✓] Checking basic markdown render....OK
    
    [✓] Checking Python 3 installation....OK
          Version: 3.11.5 (Conda)
          Path: /Users/peterchapple/anaconda3/bin/python
          Jupyter: 5.3.0
          Kernels: python3
    
    [✓] Checking Jupyter engine render....OK
    
    [✓] Checking R installation...........OK
          Version: 4.4.1
          Path: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
          LibPaths:
            - /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/library
          knitr: 1.48
          rmarkdown: 2.28
    
    [✓] Checking Knitr engine render......OK


Here is the sysInfo

    > sessionInfo()
    R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14)
    Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20
    Running under: macOS Sonoma 14.6.1
    
    Matrix products: default
    BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib 
    LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.12.0
    
    locale:
    [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
    
    time zone: Australia/Melbourne
    tzcode source: internal
    
    attached base packages:
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
    
    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
    [1] compiler_4.4.1    tools_4.4.1       rstudioapi_0.17.1


Can anyone help with this ???
Peter

Does it work if you add a triple backquote line after the mermaid diagrams?

Thanks Heiko - no it doesn't ... there are characters after that the end of the mermaid code but the SO code quoting seems to remove them otherwise the code chunk gets broken at the line

You have to make sure all your code is aligned to the left side of your script to make sure Quarto nows the header structure. Also you can use your mermaid chunk inside the ::: structure like this:
---
title: | 
        | XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        | XXXXXXXXXX
subtitle: |
        | xxxxxxxxxxx
        |
        | 1st Edition
date-format:  "YYYY"
date: last-modified
lang: en-GB
format:
    pdf:
        indent: false
fontsize: "10"
---
       
# Preface
    
Blah Blah Blah
    
## Flow chart
    
::: {#fig-BitDepth}
    
    ```{mermaid}
    %%| fig-width: 5
    flowchart LR
      A[analogue data] --> B(pre amplifier)
      B --> C{ADC}
      C --> D[14 bit ADC 16384 levels]
      C --> E[24 bit ADC 16777216 levels]
  
    ```
    
Signal processing pathway and the effect of ADC bit depth on resolution.

:::
    
## Flow chart2
    
::: {#fig-BitDepth2}
    
    ```{mermaid}
    %%| fig-width: 5
    flowchart LR
      A[analogue data] --> B(pre amplifier)
      B --> C{ADC}
      C --> D[14 bit ADC 16384 levels]
      C --> E[24 bit ADC 16777216 levels]
    ```
Signal processing pathway and the effect of ADC bit depth on resolution.

:::

Output:


Hi Quinten - I have reproduced the code as you formatted it but unfortunately it still hangs ... consistent with the behaviour so far if I comment out the second chunk it renders correctly ...
